# Can I play high end games on my rooted low end phone

Tags: rooting, internal-storage, ram

I own a spice phone which have low internal memory and ram but it is rooted. My question is that is it possible to play high end games like GTA vice city or nfs on that phone.  I had Googled about it but it makes more confusion. Some sites say yes and some no. Can anybody tell exactly the answer. It is running on android 4.2 and I had played some big games like angry birds epic and prince of persia on my device. They worked great. I can increase internal memory and ram also but after that, do really big games will work. Though GTA is a very large file so please help me solving this.

Comment: Lack of storage space is not going to be your only problem. If the processor and graphics chip aren't powerful enough, there's really nothing you can do. Low-end means "not designed for more complex tasks", like running more elaborate games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, just having your phone rooted does not make it Memory efficient  and that means it will not automatically become suitable for high end mobile games.

Rooting phone gives you additional privileges, one of most common of which is a privilege to remove system apps that are shipped by your device manufacturer.

You can try this yourself, by downloading some bulky apps from Play store and soon when you will reach device memory threshold, you will find that Android OS will complain and ask you to free some memory, albeit your phone is Rooted.

Good Luck!!

Comment: Yes friend, i have downloaded GTA vc. It runs great but with some lagging after making ram 1 GB. So thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible? Yes, if you do enough tweaking to the graphics drivers so it doesn't crash or at least renders something. Some graphical effects may not work properly or it may be extremely slow, or you may have to add swap space, or edit the apk to skip particularly intensive parts. You can always make any games "work" with enough effort.

Is it a good idea? No, in general, it's not worth the effort. The experience would be so crappy, the developer wouldn't want to support it, and you'll just make it frustrating for yourself. There are many great games that runs well on low end phones, why would you want to play a choppy, inferior version of a game on a device that just cannot play it? If you still want to play it without having to spend on a high end device, IMO, it's better to just wait a few years until the new low end devices become powerful enough for that game.

[image: I remember trying to log in to the original Command and Conquer servers a year or two back and feeling like I was knocking on the boarded-up gates of a ghost town.]

Credit: [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/606/)